# MySql Join Tables with List of Indexes in one table's Column?

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL database with two tables, Users and Games.  Basically each user has a unique ID and a set of games that they are playing and each game table has an ID and HasStarted flag (when HasStarted = false players can join the game). The table was set up so the users list of games a string of ID numbers separated by semi-colons (EX: 1;3;5; means they are part of game 1, 3, and 5). *Create examples at bottom*

What I would like to do is fetch all the games that are joinable AND that they are not already a part of.

I tried using

```
SELECT * FROM games INNER JOIN users ON games.GID = users.gamelist 
                    WHERE games.status = 0;
```

but that only matches the games based on the first game in their list.  What I'm going to do for now is just fetch all the joinable games into an array and then get the player's list of games and drop those but I was wondering if there was a way to fetch them all in one query. Does anyone know if I can do something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE users 
    (UID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     PRIMARY KEY(UID), 
     games TINYTEXT)

CREATE TABLE games
    (GID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     PRIMARY KEY(GID),
     has_started BIT)
```

Comment: You have a really bad schema.  Are you open to schema change suggestions?

Comment: If I had a penny for every time this question has been asked...

Comment: I am 100% open to schema changes because another group partner set up the table and I don't like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You REALLY should alter your schema to have a users_to_games table to normalize your data.  The setup could look like this:

```
users
------
uid - primary key
[other fields specific to a single user]

games
------
gid - primary key
has_started
[other fields specific to a single game]

users_to_games
--------------
uid - first field in compound primary key
gid - second field in compound primary key
```

There would be one record in users_to_games for every game a particular user is involved in.

Now in order to get your list of games that have not started but user has not joined you could do this:

```
SELECT gid, [any other fields from game table you want for display]
FROM games
WHERE is_started = 0
AND gid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT gid FROM users_to_games WHERE uid = ?)
```

Comment: Woah, that pretty slick. I let my partner set up the database while I did the first few webpages so I don't know much about it. Do you have a site you recommend for learning best practices?

Comment: @WhiteWolf333 I don't have a specific site to point you to.  It's mostly a matter of gaining experience over time and Googling a lot.  YOu can certainly beginning books on MySQL, relational databases, etc.